# jQuery: Why do I have to click several times in IE9?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to send the data to the server by the post method. The function is activated on click on the span tags inside the html page. Posted data set a php session variable and after that the page needs to be reloaded. Everything is working fine in Chrome, but in IE9, I have to click several times to see the effect. If I put an alert inside the function, it works fine (but I do not want that alert).

I am not an experienced user of jQuery.

Here is the code of the jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#ciril").click(function(){
   $.post('myphpfile.php', { 'lang' : 'cir'});
   location.reload();
    });
   $("#latin").click(function(){
   $.post('myphpfile.php', { 'lang' : 'lat'});
   location.reload();
  });
  });
```

and here are the span tags

```
 <span id="latin">Text1</span>
 <span id="ciril">Text2</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT want to do a location reload when you use Ajax since it sort of negates the point of using Ajax in the first place.

If you insist on doing it anyway, you need to reload in the callback

```
$(function(){
  $("#ciril").on("click",function(){
    $.post('myphpfile.php', { 'lang' : 'cir'}, function() {
     location.reload();
  });
  $("#latin").on("click",function(){
    $.post('myphpfile.php', { 'lang' : 'lat'}, function() {
     location.reload();
  });
});
```

If the page you are loading is the same page you are on, simply submit a form and have the server return the page to you

Here is a neater way

```
 <span class="lang" id="lat">Text1</span>
 <span class="lang" id="cir">Text2</span>
```

Using

```
$(function(){
  $(".lang").on("click",function(){
    $.post('myphpfile.php', { 'lang' : this.id }, function() {
     location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! The first advice is working fine. I understand your suggestion about reloading, but I need to change the whole page content depending on the click (in fact this is the way how I switch the page from cyrilic to latin characters and vice versa). I do not know the way how to do all that without reloading the page (and to do that for each page), since the translating function is in php script.

Comment: Since you have to reload, why not just load the page directly with &lang=lat or &lang=cyr instead of wasting an Ajax call?

Comment: Thanks again. First, I planned to put the translator in the client side, since I am using the same language with two alphabets (serbian language) and the translating function is not complicated. So, I am sure it is possible to completely put the translation in the client side. However, I stil did not  develop these jquery functions for translating, so I use php for that and that is the reason of using postback and reload. Things were ok in chrome and Firefox, but in IE was the problem. Thank you for helping me to resolve it.